# STI, one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and I'm kind of stuck with this design problem, that might be easy to solve, but I don't get anywhere:
I have two different kinds of advertisements: highlights and bargains. Both of them have the same attributes: title, description and one image (with paperclip). They also have the same kind of actions to apply on them: index, new, edit, create, update and destroy.

I set a STI like this:

Ad Model: ad.rb

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Bargain Model: bargain.rb

```
class Bargain < Ad
end
```

Highlight Model: highlight.rb

```
class Highlight < Ad
end
```

The problem is that I'd like to have only one controller (`AdsController`) that executes the actions I said on bargains or highlights depending on the URL, say www.foo.com/bargains[/...] or www.foo.com/highlights[/...].

For example:

- GET www.foo.com/highlights => a list of all the ads that are highlights.
- GET www.foo.com/highlights/new => form to create a new highlight
  etc...

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

First. Add some new routes:

```
resources :highlights, :controller => "ads", :type => "Highlight"
resources :bargains, :controller => "ads", :type => "Bargain"
```

And fix some actions in `AdsController`. For example:

```
def new
  @ad = Ad.new()
  @ad.type = params[:type]
end
```

**For best approach for all this controller job look [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller/5254995#5254995)**

That's all. Now you can go to `localhost:3000/highlights/new` and new `Highlight` will be initialized.

Index action can look like this:

```
def index
  @ads = Ad.where(:type => params[:type])
end
```

Go to `localhost:3000/highlights` and list of highlights will appear.
Same way for bargains: `localhost:3000/bargains`

etc

**URLS**

```
<%= link_to 'index', :highlights %>
<%= link_to 'new', [:new, :highlight] %>
<%= link_to 'edit', [:edit, @ad] %>
<%= link_to 'destroy', @ad, :method => :delete %>
```

for being polymorphic :)

```
<%= link_to 'index', @ad.class %>
```

Comment: Yes!! Thanks, it works great!! I knew there was a way to do this in a DRY and RESTful manner. The only problem I get now is how to set the paths and urls correctly, depending on the ad type. I guess I can do it just checking the type value, but i dont find that, very smart... any ideas?

Comment: well, I'm done, I've used [polymorphic_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_path) to set up the paths in the views as well as Alan's idea (just below) to use the proper class depending on the URL (highlights or bargains)... I'm not fully convinced, but it works and looks ok.

Comment: Hmmm... i don't know about that... when you have one single controller wich uses the sames views, in this case, ads_controller, you shouldn't specify :highlights, or :bargains. The way I did it: `link_to "new", new_polymorphic_path(@ad.class)`

Comment: you can :). It will send you to, for example, `higlights_path` wich reffers to `ads_controller`. Just try it :). Actually this is polymorphic_path as well

Comment: Yeah, you can, but what I mean is that, that view might be called with a bargain or a highlight object. Using plymorphic_path, it doesn't matter, this helper figures it out for you... I don't know if i'm being clear... :(

Comment: oh, I Got it. you can try `<%= link_to 'index', @ad.class %>` as well as short form for polymorphic_path

Comment: If you watn to test such controllers with rspec, use `xhr :get, :new, :use_route => 'new_ highlights'`

Comment: I suggest setting a dynamic constant, e.g., `AdType` in a before_filter to make the code a little easier to look at.

Answer (score 65):

fl00r has a good solution, however I would make one adjustment.

This may or may not be required in your case. It depends on what behavior is changing in your STI models, especially validations & lifecycle hooks.

Add a private method to your controller to convert your type param to the actual class constant you want to use:

```
def ad_type
  params[:type].constantize
end
```

The above is insecure, however. Add a whitelist of types:

```
def ad_types
  [MyType, MyType2]
end

def ad_type
  params[:type].constantize if params[:type].in? ad_types
end
```

More on the rails constantize method here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize

Then in the controller actions you can do:

```
def new
  ad_type.new
end

def create
  ad_type.new(params)
  # ...
end

def index
  ad_type.all
end
```

And now you are using the actual class with the correct behavior instead of the parent class with the attribute type set.

Comment: FWIW, I had to set the create method to be: ad_type.new(params[params[:type].downcase])

Comment: I think your method should be updated to `params[:type].underscore`. Example: if your type is `BrandNewType` then you should refer to `params['brand_new_type']` not `params['brandnewtype']`

Comment: **Do not use this method as-is in production code.**  It may not be obvious at first, but by default, this Ad#ad_type method implicitly trusts user-supplied data, breaking a basic rule of web app security.  Imagine a POST request to `/ads?type=User` with a payload including `is_admin=1` (or whatever is applicable to the authentication mechanism in use).  Now the attacking user has their own user account with admin rights!  (Technically, this attack vector could be defeated by altering or removing the default `ads` routes, but a new route later could unwittingly open the hole again.)

Comment: Solution to the security issue is to provide a whitelist. Something like: `allowed_types = [MyType, MyType2]`, then `params[:type].constantize if params[:type].in? allowed_types`

Comment: The array of valid `ad_types` must be converted to strings before checking for the inclusion of `params[:type]`

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to include this link because there are a number of interesting tricks all related to this topic.

[Alex Reisner - Single Table Inheritance in Rails](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails)

Comment: I wrote an article about STI in Rails 3 based in some part on Reisner's article. My post discusses using a single controller to serve multiple STI classes. http://www.christopherbloom.com/2012/02/01/notes-on-sti-in-rails-3-0/

Comment: the link changed to http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question by here is a pattern I like which includes the answers from @flOOr and @Alan_Peabody. (Tested in Rails 4.2, probably works in Rails 5)

In your model, create your whitelist at startup. In dev this must be eager loaded.

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
    Rails.application.eager_load! if Rails.env.development?
    TYPE_NAMES = self.subclasses.map(&:name)
    #You can add validation like the answer by @dankohn
end
```

Now we can reference this whitelist in any controller to build the correct scope, as well as in a collection for a :type select on a form, etc.

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_ad, :only => [:show, :compare, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def new
        @ad = ad_scope.new
    end

    def create
        @ad = ad_scope.new(ad_params)
        #the usual stuff comes next...
    end

    private
    def set_ad
        #works as normal but we use our scope to ensure subclass
        @ad = ad_scope.find(params[:id])
    end

    #return the scope of a Ad STI subclass based on params[:type] or default to Ad
    def ad_scope
        #This could also be done in some kind of syntax that makes it more like a const.
        @ad_scope ||= params[:type].try(:in?, Ad::TYPE_NAMES) ? params[:type].constantize : Ad
    end

    #strong params check works as expected
    def ad_params
        params.require(:ad).permit({:foo})
    end
end
```

We need to handle our forms because the routing should to be sent to the base class controller, despite the actual :type of the object. To do this we use "becomes" to trick the form builder into correct routing, and the :as directive to force the input names to be the base class as well. This combination allows us to use unmodified routes (resources :ads) as well as the strong params check on the params[:ad] coming back from the form.

```
#/views/ads/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@ad.becomes(Ad), :as => :ad) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rewritten with simpler solution that works fully:]

Iterating on the other answers, I have come up with the following solution for a single controller with Single Table Inheritance that works well with Strong Parameters in Rails 4.1. Just including :type as a permitted parameter caused an `ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound` error if an invalid type is entered. Moreover, type is not updated because the SQL query explicitly looks for the old type. Instead, `:type` needs to be updated separately with update_column if it is different than what is current set and is a valid type. Note also that I've succeeded in DRYing up all lists of types.

```
# app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  COMPANY_TYPES = %w[Publisher Buyer Printer Agent]
  validates :type, inclusion: { in: COMPANY_TYPES,
    :message => "must be one of: #{COMPANY_TYPES.join(', ')}" }
end

Company::COMPANY_TYPES.each do |company_type|
  string_to_eval = <<-heredoc
    class #{company_type} < Company
      def self.model_name  # http://stackoverflow.com/a/12762230/1935918
        Company.model_name
      end
    end
  heredoc
  eval(string_to_eval, TOPLEVEL_BINDING)
end
```

And in the controller:

```
  # app/controllers/companies_controller.rb
  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])

    # This separate step is required to change Single Table Inheritance types
    new_type = params[:company][:type]
    if new_type != @company.type && Company::COMPANY_TYPES.include?(new_type)
      @company.update_column :type, new_type
    end

    @company.update(company_params)
    respond_with(@company)
  end
```

And routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :companies
  Company::COMPANY_TYPES.each do |company_type|
    resources company_type.underscore.to_sym, type: company_type, controller: 'companies', path: 'companies'
  end
  root 'companies#index'
```

Finally, I recommend using the [responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) gem and setting scaffolding to use a responders_controller, which is compatible with STI. Config for scaffolding is:

```
# config/application.rb
    config.generators do |g|
      g.scaffold_controller "responders_controller"
    end
```

Comment: I like the validator. Check out my variation which builds the whitelist based on subclass, and adjusts forms instead of needing routes for each type. This is good if you have a ton of nested routes and don't want a huge block of near-duplicates for each of many subclasses.