# Rails controller names with dashes instead of underscores

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, seo

Is it possible to forces Rails to use dashes (-) instead of underscores when referring to controllers.

There currently exists a nice function of the `Inflector` called `parameterize`. It allows for very nice permalinks with all special characters removed and replaced with dashes...

However, when using controllers that have multiple words (like `contact_methods_controller.rb` for example), you define your route:

```
resources :contact_methods
```

This creates a map to `/contact_methods` (NOT `/contact-methods`). When I mix these two, I get ugly URLs like:

```
/contact_methods/1-preferred-email
```

I'd like to have Rails map controllers with dashes instead of underscores. All my research says to individually map each controller:

```
match 'contact-methods(/:action)' => 'contact_methods'
```

but that is really stupid, in my opinion, and it becomes messy if I'm nesting resources... I shouldn't have to define these as custom routes. Is there a setting in `ActionDispatch` that automatically rewrites these things? I can't find one...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your route.rb

```
resources "contact-methods", :controller => :contact_methods, :as => :contact_methods
```

**Edit:** You have to specify the `:as => ...` path or else `ActionDispatch` throws a fit...

Comment: haha I was getting there... I commented before I started editing :)

Comment: no, thank you... can I ask where you found this?/how you knew this?

Comment: I was researching implementing STI routing (this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller/5252136#5252136), so I've read API for `resources` here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Resources/resources