# Handling forms with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, single-table-inheritance

I have a form in my Profile edit view beginning with this line:

```
<% form_for @profile, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Profile undergoes Single Table Inheritance and the two subclasses are Profile::Artist and Profile::Listener.

When I try to access the edit view for the profile, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Profiles#edit

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/profiles/edit.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `profile_artist_path' for #<#<Class:0x103359a18>:0x1033560c0>
```

where lines 1 is the line of code for the form that I posted above. How can I fix this error?

UPDATE:

I added this code to my Profile model:

```
def self.inherited(child)
  child.instance_eval do
    def model_name
      Vehicle.model_name
    end
  end
  super
end
```

And now my error has changed to:

```
NameError in Profiles#edit

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/profiles/edit.html.erb where line #1 raised:

uninitialized constant Profile::Vehicle
```

UPDATE 2:

I changed the first line of the form to:

```
<% form_for(:profile, @profile, :url => {:controller => "profiles", :action => "update"}, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

and the submit button to `<%= f.submit :profile %>`

Now I just get a routes error...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller/5252136#5252136

Comment: Also it still seems like a routing error: `undefined method profile_artist_path`

Comment: woops, that should have been Profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not `Vehile` but `Profile`!

```
def self.inherited(child)
  child.instance_eval do
    def model_name
      Profile.model_name
    end
  end
  super
end
```

or

```
def self.model_name
  name = "profile"
  name.instance_eval do
    def plural;   pluralize;   end
    def singular; singularize; end
    def i18n_key; singularize; end
    def human(*args); singularize; end
  end
  return name
end
```

**UPDATE**

An actual problem was in form. You should add `:method => :put`

```
<%= form_for(@profile, :html => { :multipart => true, :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: nah Profile is the parent class, not Artist

Comment: By the way I use second approach ordinary

Comment: Ok check out the new form code I posted... it seems to work except for a routing error when the form is updated...

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could provide examples for the routes I should add.

Comment: Not a big deal but you should use `<%= form_for` instead of `<% form_for`. About your issue: you don't need to specify any new routes. Just try to use my second approach. remove your `self.inherited` and add `self.model_name` method

Comment: I still get a routing error... did you check my current form code?

Comment: @fl00r would you mind coming into the RoR chatroom? I think this would go a lot smoother