# rails routing aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing, custom-routes

I have a model called `Spaces` which has different types of places... such as Bars, Restaurants, etc.  It has the same columns, same, model, controller, etc. no fancy STI, I just have one field called `Space_type` which I would like to determine an aliased route.

Instead of  `domain.com/spaces/12345` it would be `/bars/12345` or `/clubs/12345`

Currently I have:

```
  resources :spaces do
    collection do
      get :update_availables
      get :update_search
      get :autocomplete
    end
    member do
      post :publish
      post :scrape
    end
    resources :photos do
      collection do
        put :sort
      end
    end

    resources :reviews
  end
```

Also, Is there a way I can do this so that anytime I use the space_url it can figure out which one to use?

Answer (score 6):

The routes are not a way to interact with your model directly. So, as long as you write a standard route, you can make things work. For instance, to make `/bars/12345` and `/clubs/12345` for your `spaces_controller` (or whatever the name of the controller is) , you can create routes like :

```
scope :path => '/bars', :controller => :spaces do
  get '/:id' => :show_bars, :as => 'bar'
end  

scope :path => '/clubs', :controller => :spaces do
  get '/:id' => :show_clubs, :as => 'clubs'
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
# routes.rb
match "/:space_type/:id", :to => "spaces#show", :as => :space_type

# linking
link_to "My space", space_type_path(@space.space_type, @space.id)
```

which will generate this urls: `/bars/123`, `/clubs/1` ... any `space_type` you have

And it looks like STI wold do this job little cleaner ;)

**UPD**

Also you can add constraints to prevent some collisions:

```
match "/:space_type/:id", :to => "spaces#show", :as => :space_type, :constraints => { :space_type => /bars|clubs|hotels/ }
```

And yes - it is good idea to put this rout in the bottom of all other routes

You can also wrap it as a helper (and rewrite your default `space_url`):

```
module SpacesHelper
  def mod_space_url(space, *attrs)
    # I don't know if you need to pluralize your space_type: space.space_type.pluralize
    space_type_url(space.space_type, space.id, attrs)
  end
end
```

Comment: wouldn't "/:space_type/:id", :to => "spaces#show", :as => :space_type interfere with all the rest of my controllers unrelated to spaces?

Comment: No it won't. About STI, linking and routing check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller/5252136#5252136

Comment: You need to ensure that "/:space_type/:id" goes below your other top level resource declarations in config/routes.rb for this to not interfere.  Rails can always route itself, but if you declare a "resources :waffles" below the custom matcher, someone can navigate to "/waffles/1234" and it will route that to the spaces controller as a waffle type.