# Single Table Inheritance and routing in Ruby on Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, sti

I am having some trouble getting routing to play nicely with Single Table Inheritance in my Ruby on Rails application. I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.6. This is in development so the back-end is SQLite3, in case that makes a difference.

Let's say I have two products, `widgets` and `sprockets`. My application keeps track of bug numbers and support case tickets for both the products but the bugs and support tickets themselves are stored in other systems. There are two separate teams that work on these two products.

I have implemented Single Table Inheritance for the two types of bug records because the validation rules for widget bug numbers and sprockets bug numbers are different (the two teams use different bug tracking systems) and there is a possibility that I will have to add further products to the application that behave wildly differently. Using STI gives me the flexibility to implement additional methods and properties as required.

The widgets team only cares about widgets information and the sprockets team only cares about sprockets information. There is a third team that needs to be able to view the information on both the widgets and the sprockets. The widgets team will access the application using the path `/widgets` and the sprockets team will access the application using the path `/sprockets`. I set this up in `routes.rb` using namespaces:

```
resources :bugs

namespace "widgets" do
  resources :bugs
end

namespace "sprockets" do
  resources :bugs
end
```

I have set up the following models which work as expected when I fire up irb and use `WidgetBug.create()` or `SprocketBug.create()`:

bug.rb

```
class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

widget_bug.rb

```
class WidgetBug < Bug
  # Some validation rules
end
```

sprocket_bug.rb

```
class SprocketBug < Bug
  # Some different validation rules
end
```

I used scaffolding to create the controller and the view for the bug object, then modified the controller to try to generalize it so it could be used with both widgets bugs and sprockets bugs. For example, the `index` method looks like this:

```
  def index
    # The scaffold code lists all bugs, which is not what we want
    # @bugs = Bug.all

    # Only return bugs of the subclass we're looking for
    @bugs = eval("#{params[:controller].classify}.all")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @bugs }
    end
  end
```

I then used `create()` to populate the database with several bugs of each type. Unfortunately when I browse to `/widgets/bugs`, the bugs for both products appear. After some debugging, I determined that the classify call is returning `Widgets::Bugs` or `Sprockets::Bugs`, so when I call all on it, it appears to be running against the superclass instead of running against the subclass.

I've reviewed the routing documentation and done quite a bit of searching on Google but I'm still at a loss as to how I can change the routing or the controller to make this work correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/5246767/298624

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this post: [STI, one controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller)

Routes

```
resources :widgets, :controller => "bugs", :type => "Widget"
resources :sprockets, :controller => "bugs", :type => "Sprocket"
# And I don't know if you need this
resources :bugs, :type => "Bug"
```

Controller

```
def index
  @bugs = params[:type].constantize.all
end
```

**UPD**

```
namespace "widgets" do
  resources :bugs, :type => "Widget"
end

namespace "sprockets" do
  resources :bugs, :type => "Sprocket"
end
```

Comment: This is extremely close to what I'm looking for but not quite exact. This allows me to access the widgets bugs under `/widgets` but what I'm looking to do is access the widgets bugs under `/widgets/bugs`. Is this possible?

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks! One important caveat I discovered when I regenerated the code from scratch - there MUST be an empty directory called `widgets` in the controllers directory or visiting `/widgets/bugs` will fail with **Routing Error** uninitialized constant Widgets.

Comment: It is very strange bug and I even can't represent it :)

Comment: Two years later, but I found this via google so: *Do not* use constantize on user-input strings!. All sorts of evil can escape into the rest of your code that way. Construct a white-list, at least.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a blog post on STI in Rails 3 that discusses some common pitfalls and proper work arounds, including the problem you mention. http://www.christopherbloom.com/2012/02/01/notes-on-sti-in-rails-3-0/