# STI and Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my models I use STI like this

Vehicle Model: vehicle.rb

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Car Model: car.rb

```
class Car < Ad
end
```

Bus Model: bus.rb

```
class Bus < Ad
end
```

Which is the most efficient way to use only one controller?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do with in the controller?

Comment: Does this answer your question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller

Comment: I think yes. Can someone provide an example for Model's tables as well? And another question will my existing links work? for example `vehicles_path` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best way is to do it like this: (I am not sure if this is the best and more efficient way)

First. Add some new routes:

```
resources :cars, :controller => "vehicle", :type => "Car"
resources :buses, :controller => "vehicle", :type => "Bus"
```

Add a private method to your controller to convert your type param to the actual class constant you want to use:

```
def vehicle_type
  params[:type].constantize
end
```

Then in the controller actions you can do:

```
def new
  vehicle_type.new
end

def create
  vehicle_type.new(params)
  # ...
end

def index
  vehicle_type.all
end
```

**URLS**

```
<%= link_to 'index', :cars %>
<%= link_to 'new', [:new, :car] %>
<%= link_to 'edit', [:edit, @vehicle] %>
<%= link_to 'destroy', @vehicle, :method => :delete %>
```

for being polymorphic :)

```
<%= link_to 'index', @vehicle.class %>
```

PS: My answer was taken from stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller and my experience