# Rails -- Single Table Inheritance and Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, single-table-inheritance

I a implementing single table inheritance but am having some trouble with the routing.  I have two classes, Gamma and Beta, and both inherit from Alpha.  I know that if I want to use Alpha as the controller as opposed to individual controllers for Beta and Gamma, I can follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller) for having a resource default to another controller.

However, what I want to do is have some methods be handled by a central Alpha controller (e.g. edit and update), while other methods be handled by the subclass Beta and Gamma controllers.  How can I specify which methods should be pointed to the Alpha controller and which should remain to be handled by Beta and Gamma?

Comment: Do you require the addresses to be ../alpha/edit or can they be ../beta/edit and ../gamma/edit?

Comment: I suppose ideally I'd like all of those to work but to point to the edit method in the alpha controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inheritance with your controllers.  Implement your edit and update functions in an `AlphaController` class, and then inherit from that class in you `BetaController` and `GammaController` classes, where you then implement your other functions.

```
class AlphaController < ActionController::Base

   def edit
      ...
   end

   def update
      ...
   end

end

class BetaController < AlphaController

   def index
      ...
   end

end
```

Note that this will make your URLs .../beta/edit and .../beta/update.

You would only want to use the views/alpha/edit.html.erb as a partial view, and then render the alpha view page as a partial in your beta/gamma views.

Remember that even though you are storing the objects in one table Alpha, you still have two classes in your model, Beta and Gamma, and should treat them as such.

Comment: Is this in addition to modifying the routes file with `resources :betas, :controller => "alphas"` etc. or do I not touch my routes file?

Comment: You shouldn't need to touch your routes file.  The BetaController will inherit the implementation of edit or update from the AlphaController so that when .../beta/edit is accessed, it is as if you have defined that edit function for the BetaController.

Comment: Ok, but what if I have a single view in views/alphas/edit.html.erb that I want to be rendered for both beta and gamma?  Is there a way to do this without making a file in the beta and gamma views that explicitly renders the alpha view page?

Comment: @Kvass you need to check this out http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance, if you are using rails 3.1

Comment: I'm using 3.0.7 -- is it a rails 2 v. rails 3 distinction or 3 v 3.1 distinction?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your questions.