# How to use link_to in STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have different STI models but want to link to them in a generic way.

The base class is Page
and several STI classes are like Book, News etc.

I want the following code link to relevant controller based on the type column on STI

```
link_to @page.title, @page
```

For eg. the above code needs to link to book_path if @page is of 'book' type.

How do I do that?

Comment: what do mean by relevant  controller ?? I think your link is already belong to relevant controller.. explain the scenario properly..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Polymorphic Routes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html).  I think this will be what you'll want to use to make this work.

Also, [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246767/sti-one-controller) question talks a bit about STI and `polymorphic_url`.

Comment: The polymorphic routes link points to the deprecated version. I think you want this one: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url

Comment: Basically, add something like `resources :books, :controller => "pages", :type => "Book"` to your routes.rb file.

Comment: here use this official link instead slow and deprecated apidock https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Answer (score 0):

you could use [polymorphic routes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)

example

`<%= link_to @page.title, polymorphic_path(@page) %>`

Comment: dude I got confused by my own answer